# Java portal architectural considerations

Tags: java, architecture, portal

Currently there exists a need to create an application that will serve 5 different customers each requiring their own specific URL and content repository.  My question is when designing this application what should my considerations be for protecting the content of the individual customers while meeting the requirements of the unique URL.  The system will be sitting on Windows  with a postgres database and java as the implementation language.

Comment: I think you should post that question on startups.com, here people will just hate on you and close your question faster than you can blink. There is a lot of smart people at startups.com, just sayin'. TO be fair to them its kind of subjective(forbidden) topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand to the following :

> each requiring their own specific URL

x

> meeting the requirements of the unique
>   URL

But I sense what you want to do. The fact that there would be 5 groups/communities of users makes the application quite complicated. You are not explaining yourself much so I can refer to Liferay portal, which practically implements everything you need : user/group management and content repository.

If you don't mind that it is a portlet container, then developing a simple portlet that handles various groups of users that operate on content repository of various resources, could be much easier than programming it from scratch. It's all done, you just set it up.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at something like liferay.com. It is a portal server. Each Client can be setup as their own community with in the portal server. Each community can be setup as a Virtual Host so you can setup a Domain for each client. Liferay can sit ontop of Postgres with no problem. It is a java application. There is an open source and a commerical license.

Your clients can also maintain all of their own content and you don't have to worry about the other sites.